# Jenkins console output not in realtime

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

Pretty new to Jenkins and I have simple yet annoying problem. When I run job (Build) on Jenkins I am triggering ruby command to execute my test script.

Problem is Jenkins is not displaying output in real time from console. Here is trigger log.

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/foo_bar
No emails were triggered.
[foo_bar] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson4042436272524123595.sh
+ ruby /var/lib/jenkins/test-script.rb
```

Basically it hangs on this output until build is complete than it just shows full output. Funny thing is this is not consistent behavior, sometimes it works as it should. But most of the time there is no real time console output.

Jenkins version: 1.461

Comment: How powerful is the server you are running on and how long does this script take to execute? This sounds like delay due to an overloaded server to me. I have seen similar symptoms when my Jenkins master is running at full capacity.

Comment: Thank you for interests, that actually makes sense. In this case we are talking about EC2 instance `small`, http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ but it is only process running. Could it be you need more than that?

Comment: It depends how many jobs are running, but yes, I would expect to see delay if you have more than a few jobs running on a small instance simultaneously.

Comment: I have a similar problem, however, the machine is over spec'd and under utilised. Also running the python script outside of jenkins works in realtime as expected.The job calls a python script which tails the logfile of another process. The logfile updates in realtime, the jenkins output is dumped in blocks as if it's waiting to fill a buffer.

Comment: Hi Craig, you were right buffering output was a problem. Using `STDOUT.sync=true` solved the problem.

Comment: I have the same challenge with maven. All the output of a maven call is only flushed, once the call terminated. Does anyone else have this?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

To clarify some of the answers.

- `ruby` or `python` or any sensible scripting language will buffer the output; this is in order to minimize the IO; writing to disk is slow, writing to a console is slow...
- usually the data gets `flush()`'ed automatically after you have enough data in the buffer with special handling for newlines. e.g. writing a string without newline then `sleep()` would not write anything until after the `sleep()` is complete (I'm only using `sleep` as an example, feel free to substitute with any other expensive system call).

e.g. this would wait 8 seconds, print one line, wait 5 more seconds, print a second line.

```
from time import sleep

def test():
    print "ok",
    time.sleep(3)
    print "now",
    time.sleep(5)
    print "done"
    time.sleep(5)
    print "again"

test()
```

- for `ruby`, [`STDOUT.sync = true`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215455/printing-to-screen-in-a-rake-task), turns the `autoflush` on; all writes to `STDOUT` are followed by `flush()`. This would solve your problem but result in more IO.

  ```
  STDOUT.sync = true
  ```
- for `python`, you can use `python -u` or the environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` to make `stdin/stdout/stout` not buffered, but [there are other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering) that do not change `stdin` or `stderr`

  ```
  export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
  ```
- for `perl`, you have [`autoflush`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014750/autoflush-question)

  ```
  autoflush STDOUT 1;
  ```

Answer (score 16):

Make sure your script is flushing its stdout and stderr.
In my case I had a buffering issue similar to what you describe but I was using python.
The following python code fixed it for me:

```py
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

I'm not a Ruby coder, but Google reveals the following:

```rb
$stdout.flush
```

Comment: Hi, Craig thank you for the answer `STDOUT.flush` or `$stdout.flush` will work. Problem is that you will need to put many of these commands trough out the script to flush buffer when needed. I will post solution that basically covers synced buffer flush to output.

Comment: thanks, it really solved my problem, since it works well under shell without flush, therefore I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 9):

It seems to me that `python -u` works as well.

E.g. In batch command

```
python -u foo.py
```

Answer (score 4):

Easiest solution here is to turn on syncing buffer to output. Something that @Craig wrote about in his answer but one line solution that will cover whole script, and not require you to flush buffer many times.

Just write

```
STDOUT.sync = true
```

Logic behind is simple, to avoid using IO operations many times output is buffered. To disable this use

```
STDOUT.sync = false
```

This is Ruby solution ofc.

Answer (score 3):

Each of the other answers is specific to one program or another, but I found a more general solution here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25378

You can use `stdbuf` to alter the buffering behavior of any program.

In my case, I was piping output from a shell script through `tee` and `grep` to split lines into either the console or a file based on content. The console was hanging as described by OP. This solved it:

```
./slowly_parse.py login.csv |tee >(grep -v LOG: > out.csv) | stdbuf -oL -eL grep LOG:
```

Eventually I discovered I could just pass `--line-buffered` to grep for the same result:

```
./slowly_parse.py login.csv |tee >(grep -v LOG: > out.csv) | grep --line-buffered LOG:
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct in saying that you need to ensure standard output is not buffered.

The other thing to be aware of is that Jenkins itself does line by line buffering. If you have a slow-running process that emits single characters (for example, an nunit test suite summary that prints a `.` for a successful test and an `E` for an error) you will not see anything until the end of line.

[True for my Jenkins 1.572 running on a Windows box.]

Answer (score 1):

For some commands, including `tee` a the best choice for unbuffering is a program called [`unbuffer`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) from [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) package.

**Usage example:**

instead of

`somecommand | tee /some/path`

do

`somecommand | unbuffer -p tee /some/path`

**Sources and more info:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11337310/2693875
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25375/53245

Answer (score 0):

The Operating-System is buffering output-data by nature, to save CPU, and so does Jenkins.

Looks like you are using a shell-command to run your Ruby script -
I suggest running your Ruby script directly via the dedicated plugin:

[**Jenkins Ruby Plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ruby+Plugin)

(may need to install it)

Comment: I will try this, it will take some time. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, this is not working :( Tried it same results. Also as solution is not very practical since ruby code is saved in Jenkins job, version-ing is much harder that way.

Comment: I agree about the "non-source-control" nature of that solution - it is better to manage any script outside of Jenkins, and just call it from the job. (true for shell/batch blocks in Jenkins as well)

Answer (score 0):

Python buffered its output traces and print it at the end of script to minimize writing on console as writing to console is slow.

You can use following command after your traces. It will flush all traces to console, which are queued before that command.

> sys.stdout.flush()