# how to get python print result in jenkins console output

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a Python script print strings. Now when run it in Jenkins I didn't see the printed strings in Jenkins Builds' Console Output.

Anyway to achieve that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631951/jenkins-console-output-not-in-realtime

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try using `-u` (**unbuffered**) option when running the python script.

`python -u my_script.py`

Answer (score 5):

Any output to `stdout` from a process spawned by Jenkins should be captured by Console Output. One caveat is that it won't be displayed until a newline character is printed, so make sure your lines are terminated.

If you are launching python in some weird way that dis-associates it from Jenkins parent process, then I can't help you.

Comment: Thanks. It solves my problem. I used `sys.stdout.write('\r foo bar')` and `sys.stdout.flush()` to print the logs of a loop on the same line. It works as expected in my console. But in jenkins console output, the logs don't show until all are done. Now I test the value of the environmental variable `BUILD_NUMBER` to use `sys.stdout.write` or just `print`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that what you need to do is a `flush`, try:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

It should help.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer got me on the right track, however in my case, a shell script that Jenkins was running was capturing the output of the python script in a subshell to a variable i.e. `a=$(python_script)`, so it was not being echoed....

To solve the problem I just had to log to stderr instead of stdout, i.e.

```
import sys
sys.stderr.write("my info\n")
sys.stdout.flush()
```