# VS Code pytest testing doesn't display test results before all are completed?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When running pytest (xdist) tests in VS Code, test results are not displayed as soon as individual tests finishes, but only when all tests complete.

A comment to the following question, mention I should try to set `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 pytest`. However, I can't find a way to do that in the VS Code settings?

[pytest xdist plugin + jenkins: test results are not displayed on the jenkins console until all the tests complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729928/pytest-xdist-plugin-jenkins-test-results-are-not-displayed-on-the-jenkins-con)

[image]