# Jenkins console prints only logger commands from main.py

Tags: python-3.x, logging, groovy, pycharm, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline in Jenkins, which triggers a python file:

```
  status = sh script: '''
    python3 main.py --command check_artfiacts
''', returnStatus:true
```

as long I'm in the main.py, I'm getting the expected result from logger in the console:

```
2019-11-28 22:14:32,027 - __main__ - INFO - starting application from: C:\Tools\BB\jfrog_distribution_shared_lib\resources\com\amdocs\jfrog\methods, with args: C:\Tools\BB\jfrog_distribution_shared_lib\resources\com\amdocs\jfrog\methods
2019-11-28 22:14:32,036 - amd_distribution_check_artifacts_exists - INFO - Coming from func: build_aql_queries
```

however, when calling a function that exists on another python file, it doesn't work (it behaves like a normal print):

```
added helm to aql
amd_distribution_check_artifacts_exists: build_docker_aql_query_by_item
```

I know for sure it's some pipeline issue, coz when running the code from PyCharm, it prints everything as expected.
Did anyone face such an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in this thread:
[jenkins-console-output-not-in-realtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631951/jenkins-console-output-not-in-realtime)
so -u worked for me:

```
python3 -u main.py --command check_artfiacts
```